# What is "screen2" installed on my laptop?

Tags: windows-xp

I found one program called "screen2" while I am trying to remove programs unnecessary.

By clicking it, there is no further information or date installed and used whatsoever.

By Google, I cannot find related information.

I was wondering how to find the information about this program and whether it is useful or can just be removed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a system restore point (name it *"before screen2 uninstallation"*) and then uninstall that program. If you come by any problems after the uninstallation, you can get back to that restore point.